# Documentation of processors

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, raspberry-pi, embedded, microprocessor

I am an undergrad electronics student , so I have some knowledge about why certain resistors and caps are used with processors but still aloof to majority of them . When one takes look at a raspberry pi board you see a range of resistors and caps , is there any online documentation from Broadcom that instructs these resistor and caps to be placed ? If not how would one go about testing a processor ? I'm currently building an FMCW radar system and I need to develop a board containing Broadcom processor .Time isn't an issue , i'm prepared to devote my complete resources if given a hint or direction to proceed .

Thanking you

Comment: You can ask Broadcom for application information. They do most of their business with a very small number of customers and may not be all that helpful unless your company fits their plans.

Comment: Broadcom has a reputation for being very difficult to work with unless you are large potential customer.  If this is true, likely using an alternative vender's ARM processor would prove more fruitful.  As for all the supporting bits and pieces on a Raspberry Pi, the processor is not the only chip on a Raspberry Pi with specification sheets.  There are many chips on a Raspberry Pi with specification sheets which contain suggested circuits.  Most regard the task you set in front of you vary daunting.  More in line with a year + graduate project instead of a semester long undergraduate project.

Answer (score 5):

The datasheet from the manufacturer will tell you what's required.

The datasheet from Broadcom isn't available without signing an NDA. That's not the largest of your problems, because the device itself isn't available in small quantities either.

To support people building products around the Pi ecosystem, there is the Raspberry Pi Compute Module.

If you insist on building a board from scratch (not a beginner project), you could consider the Freescale iMX series which have more readily available documentation and run Linux.

Comment: Thank You . NXP looks really good . I don't intend on doing any high end processing , its merely used to transfer beat frequency data through usb to PC where the fft is done . So a processor with usb 2 would suffice i guess

Comment: If USB is the only requirements you need,using Ras pi or any other cortex A processor is wasting your time and cost,There are many cortex M based MCU from various manufacturer which completely meet your needs(e.g.ST,NXP,ATMEL,etc.). For this case I think a cortex m0 from ST or NXP is enough.(LPC11uxx from NXP is almost most economical case for you,with various example code with USB peripheral(HID,CDC,Mass storage,etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps everybody covered this already

Generally you are not going to be able to buy those processors unless you remove them from raspberry pis.

When you are working for the right company and at the right experience level to even attempt to buy these and use them, there is an NDA in place, and then you get their documentation if not access to some level of support, sometimes even having the chip vendor review your design.  For a complicated part like this they likely have a reference design (even simple parts have reference designs) and it would be in your best interest to take that design seriously when you make your own.

Some companies like broadcom will not sell or even answer your phone call unless they get something out of it, a university project sometimes helps, but usually you need to have already built a successful millions of unit product line with something else before calling them to build your next millions of units product line.  And sometimes these companies have excuses why they need to be secretive, but usually it is unfounded, doesnt matter if they are like that they are like that and you play their game or buy elsewhere.

If all you are looking for is a couple of usb ports, you are grossly shooting too high, either just buy some boards, raspberry pi or other if you feel you need them for overkill reasons, or aim more in the microcontroller range or put two mcus back to back (with some other interface) if you really need two usb ports.  Or look at ftdi or others for usb to something then use an mcu of some flavor.  ti, st, nxp, the usual players all have a wide range of parts with full documentation from 8bit processor level all the way up to cortex-m7s or cortex-As if you really really think you need that much horsepower, or are lazy on the programming side and want to use a big bulky operating system (linux).

Your specific question.  The vendor's generally provide reference designs and hardware development kits to guide you as to what the rules are for using that part, electrically.  Likewise they provide board support packages for those reference designs if they are at the level of these broadcom chips, or they provide libraries for MCU level chips.  It is in their best interest for your design to be successful if you are a serious customer so they will want you to get it right and provide what you need for that, but without burning up all the profit they were going to make off of you.

Comment: as mentioned there are vendors ti, etc, that have the docs readily available for linux capable level solutions.  And there are companies like allwinner and broadcom, that you most likely will never get access to.  But the kind of info you get from the places that will talk to you should be on par with the places that wont.  They are not successful in selling parts if you are not successful in making and selling designs with those parts.  It is that simple.